How to Compare Two Lists of Models in Flutter?
I have a model class called Media, and I want to check if two lists of Media objects are equal. Below is the code for my Media model class and two example lists.
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Media extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Media({required this.id, required this.title});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id, title];
}
 
void main() {
  List<Media> list1 = [
    Media(id: 1, title: 'Media One'),
    Media(id: 2, title: 'Media Two'),
  ];

  List<Media> list2 = [
    Media(id: 1, title: 'Media One'),
    Media(id: 2, title: 'Media Two'),
  ];

  // How to compare list1 and list2 for equality?
}

I want to compare list1 and list2 to see if they contain the same elements with the same attributes, but the order of items in the lists does not matter. How can I do this?
Thank you for your help!

Do you want the list is equal or not status like true/false?

Yes, I want to check if the data in the list has been changed or not. So just return true or false.

Check my below answer

print(setEquals(list1.toSet(), list2.toSet())); - more about setEquals here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/setEquals.html - they say: "Compares two sets for element-by-element equality.
Returns true if the sets are both null, or if they are both non-null, have the same length, and contain the same members. Returns false otherwise. Order is not compared."

you can also do final equality = UnorderedIterableEquality<Media>(); bool areEqual = equality.equals(list1, list2); and actually that way should be used instead of setEquals

Try below code hope its help to you. use toSet method for this. If you set the list vice-versa it also gives the status
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Media extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Media({required this.id, required this.title});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id, title];
}

void main() {
  List<Media> list1 = [
    Media(id: 1, title: 'Media One'),
    Media(id: 2, title: 'Media Two'),
  ];

  List<Media> list2 = [
    Media(id: 2, title: 'Media Two'),
    Media(id: 1, title: 'Media One'),
    
  ];

  bool listStatus = list1.toSet().containsAll(list2.toSet()) && 
                   list2.toSet().containsAll(list1.toSet());

  print('List Status- $listStatus');
}


you could  reduce the amount of times you call .toSet() here

setEquals already exists in flutter: print(setEquals(list1.toSet(), list2.toSet()));
